# Sphinx replace in inclusion command

Tags: python-sphinx

I am struggling with this issue:

- I have to document a fairly large project composed by a C core engine and different API that are built on top of that, say Java, Python C#.
- The docs must be deployed separately for each API, i.e. for each language, but 99% of the docs are the same, just the code snippet and example mainly need to change.
- I set the type of language in the conf.py file by defining a global variable
- I have used primary_domain and highlight_language to set the correct syntax highlighting
- For each example I have a source file with the same name but different extension

Now, I'd like to include say an example using the literalinclude directive specifying the name of the file and let its extension change depending on the language in use. I tried naively to use the replace macro but with no success:

```
rst_prolog = ".. |ext| replace:: .%s\n" % primary_domain
```

correctly replace `|ext|` around the docs, but not in the command

```
.. literalinclude: filename|ext|
```

Is there any way I can do this, except parse `rst` files using sed or the like?